# IE8 Different versions

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a problem with IE8. I have to download the document from share drive using asp.net. Its working in IE8 in one machine and is not in other machine IE8. I had a look on the IE version , but its differing.

Here is the IE8 version:
working- 8.0.7601.17514
Not working -8.0.7601.17514 **CO**

Here is the difference:- The 'CO' has been added to the not working version of IE.

Did you anyone knows what is the access rights does 'CO' is having and the other version is not.

I am having the problem only in this IE8 versions.

Comment: classic IE lol sucks so much, either way did you saw this one mate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838737/different-behavior-of-web-app-in-different-ie8-versions

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working? e.g. does the download start.. but then when the document opens up in (word?)... the file is empty?  If so, are you running this on HTTPS?... if so I might know the issue.

Comment: Whenever I click download link, it says "internet cannot be found".

Answer (score 0):

I think CO designates a "corporate" version of IE, so the problem is probably a security setting. Try going through the advanced settings part of Internet Options on both machines and make sure they're absolutely identical.

(I spent days debugging an issue with CSS the filter property a while back. Turns out they were switched off in advanced options.)